# Why does the shape of an element and logical indexed array seem to transpose dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Let's say we have a multi-dimensional array.

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.random.random((2,4,3,5))
```

Each axis is relevant for a specific feature of the data and I'm interested in a subset of the data.

I can use a logical index on axis 2 and an element index on axis 0 and 3.

```
mask = np.array([1, 1, 0], dtype=bool)

bar = foo[0,:,mask,0]
```

I expected bar to have shape (4,2). Instead, it has shape (2,4). The data within each axis is as expected. However, the axes are transposed from what I would expect.

I suspect it has something to do with broadcasting the mask, but I can't figure out a way around it.

Python 3.6.4

Numpy 1.14.0

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it's working.
When you have slices and array indexes, it broadcasts it as you said and also the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html) . Now the first and last dimensions are also indexing, so numpy is not broadcasting a two dimensional indexing array, but a four dimensional. I couldn't understand how it's exactly doing it that causes this transpose. But the workaround to get the shape you want is to generate a temporary array first so numpy doesn't broadcast the index, then use the middle indexes:

```
bar=foo[0,...,0][:,[1,2]]
```

Comment: It's not a broadcasting issue, but rather a documented behavior when a slice (basic) is used in the middle of advanced indexing, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing.  But your idea of first applying the singleton indexes is valid, since the slice is no longer in the middle.